# Dashicons and Pseudo :before

Tags: admin, icon, admin-css

I am generating a custom post type that uses the dashicons and allows users to select one to associate with the post. The idea being the user can select an icon from a drop down list and it is displayed to the right.

I have run into an issue though as javascript can't change the `:before { content: '\f188';}` value directly so I had planned on using a data-attr (data-icon) on the element then using `:before { content: attr(data-icon);}`.

This works and replaces the content with the necessary icon code but for some reason renders it as text rather than an icon. Switching back to just using the text (rather than the data attr) in the css works.

HTML:

```
<select name="_mo_content_menu_ico" id="_mo_content_menu_ico">
    <option value="\f118">Education</option>
    <option value="\f130">Status</option>...
    ...<option value="\f161">Gallery</option>
</select>
<span id="content_icon" data-icon="\f118"></span>
```

CSS:

```
#content_icon:before {
content: attr(data-icon);
font: 400 20px/1 dashicons!important;
speak: none;
color: #333;
padding: 8px 0;
height: 36px;
width: 20px;
display: inline-block;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
-moz-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}
```

JS:

```
var $j = jQuery;
$j(document).ready(function(){
    $j('#_mo_content_menu_ico').change(function(){
        var icon = $j('#_mo_content_menu_ico').val();
        $j('#content_icon').attr('data-icon',icon);
    });
});
```

Any idea how to get round this? Or even why it's happening?

Thanks,

Comment: If you're generating the CPT can you set the menu_icon to what the user selects, like `'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-id-alt'` ?

Comment: It's not being used as a menu_icon it is being used beside the header of a "technical" post in the front-end of the site. I can get the information saved fine and then access it from the front end, I just want to dynamically show the user what the icon looks like when they are selecting it and thought this might be the easiest way. I think I may have been wrong, seems to be an issue using attr and the leading slash. I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dashicons are only part of the WordPress admin area. So if you're aiming for dashicons in the frontend you'll have to enqueue the icon font within your `function.php`:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'frontend_dashicons' );
function frontend_dashicons() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'dashicons' );
}
```

Moreover you'll not need to remember those cryptic icon values like `\f161`; simply add the classname of the dashicon.

You can find all dashicons with the according classname here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/

(These classnames are part of the `dashicons.css` which is located via `wp-includes/css/dashicons.css`)

All this said, you'll only have to update the `value` to the classname of the dashicons within your HTML:

```
<select name="_mo_content_menu_ico" id="_mo_content_menu_ico">
    <option value="dashicons-welcome-learn-more">Education</option>
    <option value="dashicons-format-status">Status</option>
    <option value="dashicons-format-gallery">Gallery</option>
</select>
<span id="content_icon"></span>
```

And update the JS like this:

```
var $j = jQuery;
$j(document).ready(function(){
    $j('#_mo_content_menu_ico').change(function(){
        var icon = $j('#_mo_content_menu_ico').val();
        // clear and add selected dashicon class
        $j('#content_icon').removeClass().addClass(icon);
    });
});
```

And you'll also have to remove this line within your CSS:

```
content: attr(data-icon);
```

Comment: Thanks Sven, that's what I've ended up doing, just that way I have to use the same class values for the icon throughout the backend and copy the content:'\f...' into the css for my span element. The way I had first wanted would mean I could add new icons to the options without having to then edit the css as well. It works like that though so guess it'll do! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but if you're adding new (additional) icons, you'll probably have to update the CSS of your iconfont anyway. Would be great if you'd accept my answer :)

Comment: Hi Sven, I meant from the dashicons set not custom icons (some of them are not relevant but I might change my tune on that at some point), if I used this method then any new dashicons I added would automatically work. There might be a work around.